# Mongo Aggregate with distinct from Collection using C# Driver

Tags: c#, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have the following working aggregate statement in MongoDB:

```
db.Forms.aggregate( [
{ $match: { Id: { $nin: db.Forms.distinct("Id", {"Status": "DELETE"}, {Id: 1}) } }},
{ $group: { _id: "$Id", lastModifiedId: { $last: "$_id" } } }
]).result
```

The statement selects all Forms that do **not** have a delete record on the Forms table and returns their last modified rows.

What I would like to know is: how do I write the aggregate statement above using the MongoDB C# driver? This is what I have so far:

```
var aggregate = _forms.Aggregate()
//.Match(new BsonDocument { { "Id", new BsonDocument("$nin", "db.Forms.distinct(\"Id\", {\"Status\": \"DELETE\"}, {Id: 1})") } })
.Group(new BsonDocument { { "_id", "$Id" }, { "lastModifiedId", new BsonDocument("$last", "_id") } });

var aggregateResults = aggregate.ToListAsync().Result.ToList();
```

I just need to get the Match statement sorted out.

I've looked at a few articles about aggregation and I understand the concept (I think), but the "db.Forms.distinct" is where I'm having issues and none of the articles that I found handled this scenario.

If there's a better way of doing this, please let me know.

Thank you!

Comment: You need to run the `.distinct()` as a separate operation and use the array returned from it's results as your argument to `$nin`. That is **actually** what the shell is really doing here. Queries are not performed "lnline", they are "evaluated" and return results into the pipeline document before it is sent to the server.

Comment: Hi Blakes. Thanks again for your help, that makes sense and I thought that that would be the solution, but I just wanted to make sure. Appreciate it.